# Wireless card on my Macbook Pro which support 802.11 ac

Tags: wireless, router

I'm having the Card Type : AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xF5) which support 802.11 a/b/g/n, but this is not enough for me. As my new router is WRT 1900 ac (Linksys) and it is using the new technology 802.11 ac. I'd like to use it, but my computer doesn't support it.  My computer is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), and I'd like to change my Card Type (Apple Airport Extreme) to obtain the one which support 802.11ac. Could anyone is able to tell me what sort of card type do I have to buy and what is the price.

Comment: We need more details to realistically answer this. Specify what you want out of the new card, and it'll be much easier to answer.

Comment: Yet, my question is clear at this level. I'd like this new Airport could support the technology 802.11 ac from my new router.